# How can I convert my program to work with new c++ standard? <iostream.h> etc

Tags: c++

How can I convert my program to work with new c++ standard? I have problem with `<iostream.h>` etc.

```
main.cpp:3:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory 
#include <iostream.h>
          ^
compilation terminated.
```

Here is online compilator:

http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <conio.h>

class phoneBook{
    char name[20],phno[15];
    public:
    void getdata();
    void showdata();
    char *getname(){ return name; }
    char *getphno(){ return phno; }
    void update(char *nm,char *telno){
        strcpy(name,nm);
        strcpy(phno,telno);
    }
};

void phoneBook :: getdata(){
    cout<<"\nEnter Name : ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter Phone No. : ";
    cin>>phno;
}

void phoneBook :: showdata(){
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<setw(20)<<name;
    cout<<setw(15)<<phno;
}


void main(){
    phoneBook rec;
    fstream file;
    file.open("d:\\phone.dat", ios::ate | ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    char ch,nm[20],telno[6];
    int choice,found=0;
    while(1){
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\n*****Phone Book*****\n";
        cout<<"1) Add New Record\n";
        cout<<"2) Display All Records\n";
        cout<<"3) Search Telephone No.\n";
        cout<<"4) Search Person Name\n";
        cout<<"5) Update Telephone No.\n";
        cout<<"6) Exit\n";
        cout<<"Choose your choice : ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1 : //New Record
                 rec.getdata();
                 cin.get(ch);
                 file.write((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                 break;

            case 2 : //Display All Records
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 cout<<"\n\nRecords in Phone Book\n";
                 while(file){
                    file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                    if(!file.eof())
                        rec.showdata();
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 getch();
                 break;

            case 3 : //Search Tel. no. when person name is known.
                 cout<<"\n\nEnter Name : ";
                 cin>>nm;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    if(strcmp(nm,rec.getname())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        rec.showdata();
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 getch();
                 break;

            case 4 : //Search name on basis of tel. no
                 cout<<"\n\nEnter Telephone No : ";
                 cin>>telno;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    if(strcmp(telno,rec.getphno())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        rec.showdata();
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 getch();
                 break;

            case 5 : //Update Telephone No.
                 cout<<"\n\nEnter Name : ";
                 cin>>nm;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 int cnt=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    cnt++;
                    if(strcmp(nm,rec.getname())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 else
                 {
                    int location = (cnt-1) * sizeof(rec);
                    cin.get(ch);
                    if(file.eof())
                        file.clear();

                    cout<<"Enter New Telephone No : ";
                    cin>>telno;
                    file.seekp(location);
                    rec.update(nm,telno);
                    file.write((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                    file.flush();
                 }
                 break;
            case 6 : gotoout;
        }
    }
out:
file.close();
}
```

Comment: C++ does not have `iostream.h` it has `iostream` and `string`.

Comment: "new" C++ standard? Your code is outdated since over a century

Comment: by using #include<iostream> using namesapace std;

Comment: Don't use `char*` in C++ prefer `std::string`.

Comment: Isn't conio.h a DOS header??

Comment: `iostream.h` is not part of *any* C++ standard, new or old.

Comment: welcome to 21st century..:)

Comment: @Davidbrcz..and we will bombard his teacher with series of emails..;)

Comment: What the others try to express is mainly - 1)use <iostream>, 2)conio.h is not present on Unix/Linux (that is where online compiler runs), 3) replace *gotos* with more human friendly code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works and has updated headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class phoneBook{
    char name[20],phno[15];
    public:
    void getdata();
    void showdata();
    char *getname(){ return name; }
    char *getphno(){ return phno; }
    void update(char *nm,char *telno){
        strcpy(name,nm);
        strcpy(phno,telno);
    }
};

void phoneBook :: getdata(){
    cout<<"\nEnter Name : ";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"Enter Phone No. : ";
    cin>>phno;
}

void phoneBook :: showdata(){
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<setw(20)<<name;
    cout<<setw(15)<<phno;
}


int main(){
    phoneBook rec;
    fstream file;
    file.open("d:\\phone.dat", ios::ate | ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    char ch,nm[20],telno[6];
    int choice,found=0;
    while(1){
        system("clear");
        cout<<"\n*****Phone Book*****\n";
        cout<<"1) Add New Record\n";
        cout<<"2) Display All Records\n";
        cout<<"3) Search Telephone No.\n";
        cout<<"4) Search Person Name\n";
        cout<<"5) Update Telephone No.\n";
        cout<<"6) Exit\n";
        cout<<"Choose your choice : ";
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice){
            case 1 : //New Record
            {     rec.getdata();
                 cin.get(ch);
                 file.write((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                 break;
            }
            case 2 : //Display All Records
            {     file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 cout<<"\n\nRecords in Phone Book\n";
                 while(file){
                    file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                    if(!file.eof())
                        rec.showdata();
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 getchar();
                 break;
            }
            case 3 : //Search Tel. no. when person name is known.
            {     cout<<"\n\nEnter Name : ";
                 cin>>nm;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    if(strcmp(nm,rec.getname())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        rec.showdata();
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 getchar();
                 break;
            }
            case 4 : //Search name on basis of tel. no
            {     cout<<"\n\nEnter Telephone No : ";
                 cin>>telno;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    if(strcmp(telno,rec.getphno())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        rec.showdata();
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 getchar();
                 break;
            }
            case 5 : 
            {
                 //Update Telephone No.
                 cout<<"\n\nEnter Name : ";
                 cin>>nm;
                 file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
                 found=0;
                 int cnt=0;
                 while(file.read((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec)))
                 {
                    cnt++;
                    if(strcmp(nm,rec.getname())==0)
                    {
                        found=1;
                        break;
                    }
                 }
                 file.clear();
                 if(found==0)
                    cout<<"\n\n---Record Not found---\n";
                 else
                 {
                    int location = (cnt-1) * sizeof(rec);
                    cin.get(ch);
                    if(file.eof())
                        file.clear();

                    cout<<"Enter New Telephone No : ";
                    cin>>telno;
                    file.seekp(location);
                    rec.update(nm,telno);
                    file.write((char *) &rec, sizeof(rec));
                    file.flush();
                 }
            }     break;
            case 6 :
            {goto outLabel;}    break;
        }
    }
outLabel:
file.close();

return 0;
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

- **is C++** and if you intend to use it, you should use that as well
- cout, cin and similar **need the namespace std**
- **main should usually return int**
- Try to use C++ and **not C functions** if you intend to program in C++
- You should use **strings** instead of char arrays whenever possible (do it yourself in the above code)

Also: programming with gotos is a terrible practice and the recipe for a tasty spaghetti code:

[image]

Comment: Try to use C++ and not C functions if you intend to program in C++>> So why char[] instead of std::string ?

Comment: Thanks. I'll analyzed your changes

Comment: @Davidbrcz the program should be rewritten to deal with gotos as well, I can add that as a list item but you're not really expecting food ready, are you?

Comment: @DavidKernin  `"clear" is not recognized as an internal or external command` what this can mean?

Comment: are you running windows or linux? On linux that should work, on Windows you might have to change it to system("CLS");

Answer (score 5):

Just the list I see:

- Use `<iostream>` headers
- Pretty much the entire Standard Library is in namespace `std`
- Use std::string
- `int main`
- No easy replacement for `<conio.h>`
- Missing `const` in many places
- Drop the `goto`, C++ has always had destructors

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
```

iostream.h is old and has been replaced by iostream

Comment: Thanks but this is only one part of my problems:(

Comment: please post all your problem so we can take a look :)

Comment: "new standard" as in standardized in 1998.

Comment: it is "new" compared to the old standard :)

Comment: No, 1998 is the first standard. There is no older one.

Comment: @Herter This is old code. If I try compile here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php every import seems be not correctly `#include <conio.h>` etc.

Comment: well I stand corrected then :) - I'm not that experienced in C++ so I'm learning myself

Comment: @user3207076 Check out David Kernins and MSalters' answers - they are a whole lot more useful than mine :)